# Are IQueryable and IQueryable<T> async?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Are the interfaces `IQueryable` and `IQueryable<T>` async?

I mean, supose the following code:

```
void Method()
{
    var customers = CustomerReposity.ToQueryable(); //The execution of query starts here.

    DoSomething();

    foreach (var customer in customers) // The foreach await to finish
        customer.DoSomething();
}
```

Is my suposicion right? If not, what is the right form to achieve async behavior?

Maybe...

```
async void Method()
{
    var customers = CustomerReposity.ToQueryable().ToListAsync(); //The execution of query starts here.

    DoSomething();

    foreach (var customer in await customers) // The foreach await to finish
        customer.DoSomething();
}
```

Is this a good idea?

Comment: This question seems to be: When to use asynchronous method?

Comment: @TânNguyễn No, I know when to use asynchronimous, the question is about if IQueryable interfaces are ever or not async by default.

Comment: `IQueryable` has nothing to do with `async`. `ToListAsync` is just an extension method to convert the items to a list using asynchronous task (need `await`).

Comment: In addition to Tan's reply, `IQueryable` is more like, I'll give this to you when you need it, or deffered loading. I would not even bother _async-ing_ your first code block.

Comment: @TânNguyễn  The execution of query starts when I call `IQueryable.ToListAsync()`? Is a good idea await it on foreach because the query is running in parallel before I use the foreach? The `DoSomething()` method can be long-running.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't execute anything. It's just put the action to a task and waits until you use `await` keyword. You shouldn't use it inside `foreach` loop to prevent the case: `source` is null. Also, you cannot catch the exception inside `foreach (...)` loop,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `IQueryable` and `IQueryable<T>` are not async, and they don't need to be.  These two interfaces provide means to extract some data from a source, but it is up to the source to provide async support.  If the source will return all data in memory, using it asynchronously is pointless.  If, however, the source is "streamed" from network, then it might make sense to enumerate it asynchronously.

Comment: More accurately, **interfaces** (and interface member definitions) cannot be async. Implementations of interface members can be, as long as the method they are implementing meets the requirements to be an `async` method (such as returning `Task` or `Task<T>`).

Comment: Even more accurately only **methods** can be async. :-)

Comment: Ok, I think my question is bad formed. I know that `IQueryable` deffer execution of the query until it is converted or used in foreach. My question is about if retrieving the source of the data is a long-running proccess (like database connection), if I use an `IQueryable` or `IQueryable<T>` in foreach, the thread is blocked until I get the result? Can I start asyncronly the query execution before use it in the foreach? Are calling `IQueryable.ToAsyncEnumerable()` or `IQueryable.ToListAsync()` the right way to start the query execution before use it in a foreach?

Comment: `await xxx.ToListAsync()` will case your query to be executed asynchronously, i.e. awaiting on this method will cause your thread to return to the thread pool and be available to run other stuff until the query executes and result is returned to the database.  You code `foreach (var customer in await customers)` does exactly this.  So yes, it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Hello @Nick, thank you for comment. I've one more question, see my second block of code. Imagine `DoSomething()` is a long-running method. When I call `xxx.ToListAsync()` without awaiting it, the query execution starts and it is running at the same time that `DoSomething()`? I await the `customers` task in foreach because is when I need the task finished, but I don't need the query finished while running `DoSomething()` method.

Comment: Yes, when you call `xxx.ToListAsync()` without awaiting it, the query execution starts and you can do other things.  Do, yes, `DoSomething()` will execute in parallel while the query is executing in the background.

Comment: Thanks, this was my initally question, but I bad-formed the question. I accepted your answer.